# Python Pandas - How to match data from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes related to stocks and their prices that I'm trying to cross-match data from each dataframe.

`df1` = database of users who have each chosen a number of stocks:

```
  Username Stock 1 Stock 2
0   JB3004    TSLA    MSFT
1   JM3009    SHOP    SPOT
2   DB0208    TWTR    MSFT
3   AB3011    TWTR    PTON
4   CB3004    MSFT    TSLA
```

`df2` = Today's close price for each of the stocks:

```
               TWTR      SPOT      PTON      SHOP      MSFT      TSLA
Date           Adj Close Adj Close Adj Close Adj Close Adj Close Adj Close
2020-12-11     51.44     341.22     117.1   1057.87    213.26    609.99
```

I'm trying to match the relevant stocks for each user in `df1` to the Adj Close price in `df2` so that I can print a `df3` with the correct closing price for the stocks each user has chosen.

How would I do this? Everything I've tried doesn't come close, so need some help!

Comment: What did you try? Have you tried the `merge` method? Regardless please try merging df1 and df2 and show your code attempt. Good luck!

Comment: I cannot merge them as there is not common columns to perform merge on.

I have created a dictionary of df1 as a possible way to iterate through the dictionary and match the price. I created the dictionary by: 

dictionary = df1.set_index("Username").T.to_dict("list")

I'm then stuck as to how to iterate through the dictionary to match the prices to each stock. That's as far as I've got.

Comment: If you do something like `transpose` df2 then `reset_index()` on the transposition, that should give you the ticker symbols as new rows in column 1. Then you could merge?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problems. Then I got a solution which I am sharing with you. Hope this will help you get your answer. To see my solution, click on
[github](https://github.com/JagritiG/machine_learning/blob/main/problems/stackoverflow_panda_dataframe.ipynb)

Create df1

```
data1 = {"Username" : ["JB3004", "JM3009", "DB0208", "AB3011", "CB3004"],
      "Stock_1" : ["TSLA", "SHOP", "TWTR", "TWTR", "MSFT"],
      "Stock_2" : ["MSFT", "SPOT", "MSFT", "PTON", "TSLA"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
df1.head()
```

```
   Username Stock_1 Stock_2
0   JB3004  TSLA    MSFT
1   JM3009  SHOP    SPOT
2   DB0208  TWTR    MSFT
3   AB3011  TWTR    PTON
4   CB3004  MSFT    TSLA
```

Convert wide format to long format data

```
df1_1 = pd.wide_to_long(df1, stubnames='Stock_', i='Username', j='Stock_num')
df1_1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1_1
```

```
   Username Stock_num   Stock_
0   JB3004     1        TSLA
1   JM3009     1        SHOP
2   DB0208     1        TWTR
3   AB3011     1        TWTR
4   CB3004     1        MSFT
5   JB3004     2        MSFT
6   JM3009     2        SPOT
7   DB0208     2        MSFT
8   AB3011     2        PTON
9   CB3004     2        TSLA
```

rename the column name Stock_ to Stocks

```
df1_1.rename(columns={"Stock_": "Stocks"}, inplace=True)
df1_1
```

Create df2 to match your df2

closing_price.csv file contains the closing price data

```
# closing_price.csv
,TWTR,SPOT,PTON,SHOP,MSFT,TSLA
Date,Adj Close,Adj Close,Adj Close,Adj Close,Adj Close,Adj Close
2020-12-11,51.44,341.22,117.1,1057.87,213.26,609.99
```

Load df2

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("closing_price.csv", index_col=None)
df2.head()
```

```
Unnamed: 0       TWTR    SPOT         PTON        SHOP        MSFT        TSLA
0      Date   Adj Close Adj Close   Adj Close   Adj Close   Adj Close   Adj Close
1   2020-12-11  51.44    341.22       117.1      1057.87      213.26      609.99
```

Data cleaning and transformation

```
df2.set_index("Unnamed: 0", inplace = True)
df2.index.name = "Date"
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.drop([0], inplace=True)
df2.head()
```

```
       Date     TWTR    SPOT    PTON    SHOP    MSFT    TSLA
1   2020-12-11  51.44   341.22  117.1   1057.87 213.26  609.99
```

Convert wide format to long format data

```
# Convert wide format to long format data
df2_1 = pd.melt(df2, id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=["TWTR", "SPOT", "PTON", "SHOP", "MSFT", "TSLA"], var_name="Stocks", value_name="Adj Close")
df2_1
```

```
       Date    Stocks   Adj Close
0   2020-12-11  TWTR    51.44
1   2020-12-11  SPOT    341.22
2   2020-12-11  PTON    117.1
3   2020-12-11  SHOP    1057.87
4   2020-12-11  MSFT    213.26
5   2020-12-11  TSLA    609.99
```

Now, df1_1 and df2_1 are as below:

```
df1_1
```

```
   Username Stock_num   Stocks
0   JB3004     1         TSLA
1   JM3009     1         SHOP
2   DB0208     1         TWTR
3   AB3011     1         TWTR
4   CB3004     1         MSFT
5   JB3004     2         MSFT
6   JM3009     2         SPOT
7   DB0208     2         MSFT
8   AB3011     2         PTON
9   CB3004     2         TSLA
```

```
df2_1
```

```
      Date     Stocks   Adj Close
0   2020-12-11  TWTR    51.44
1   2020-12-11  SPOT    341.22
2   2020-12-11  PTON    117.1
3   2020-12-11  SHOP    1057.87
4   2020-12-11  MSFT    213.26
5   2020-12-11  TSLA    609.99
```

Merge df1_1 and df2_1 on column "Stocks"

```
# Merge df1_1 and df2_1 on column "Stocks"
df3 = pd.merge(df1_1, df2_1, on='Stocks')
df3
```

```
   Username Stock_num   Stocks  Date       Adj Close
0   JB3004     1        TSLA    2020-12-11  609.99
1   CB3004     2        TSLA    2020-12-11  609.99
2   JM3009     1        SHOP    2020-12-11  1057.87
3   DB0208     1        TWTR    2020-12-11  51.44
4   AB3011     1        TWTR    2020-12-11  51.44
5   CB3004     1        MSFT    2020-12-11  213.26
6   JB3004     2        MSFT    2020-12-11  213.26
7   DB0208     2        MSFT    2020-12-11  213.26
8   JM3009     2        SPOT    2020-12-11  341.22
9   AB3011     2        PTON    2020-12-11  117.1
```

Rearrange columns

```
# Rearrange columns
df3.set_index(["Date"], inplace=True)
df3.reset_index(inplace=True)
df3
```

```
       Date    Username   Stock_num Stocks  Adj Close
0   2020-12-11  JB3004       1      TSLA    609.99
1   2020-12-11  CB3004       2      TSLA    609.99
2   2020-12-11  JM3009       1      SHOP    1057.87
3   2020-12-11  DB0208       1      TWTR    51.44
4   2020-12-11  AB3011       1      TWTR    51.44
5   2020-12-11  CB3004       1      MSFT    213.26
6   2020-12-11  JB3004       2      MSFT    213.26
7   2020-12-11  DB0208       2      MSFT    213.26
8   2020-12-11  JM3009       2      SPOT    341.22
9   2020-12-11  AB3011       2      PTON    117.1
```

```
# Reshaping or pivoting data based on column values
df = df3.pivot(index="Username", columns="Stock_num", values=["Stocks", "Adj Close"])
df
```

```
           Stocks        Adj Close
Stock_num 1      2       1       2
Username                
AB3011  TWTR    PTON    51.44   117.1
CB3004  MSFT    TSLA    213.26  609.99
DB0208  TWTR    MSFT    51.44   213.26
JB3004  TSLA    MSFT    609.99  213.26
JM3009  SHOP    SPOT    1057.87 341.22
```

Comment: put your solution here

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this and I thought I'd give it a whirl.

Use pandas.DataFrame.stack() on df2 to align everything with df1.  Rename some fields, if you want.

```
df2t = df2.stack().reset_index().rename(
        columns={
                "level_0":"date",
                "level_1":"stock",
                0:"closing_price",
                },
        )

df2t = df2t.loc[df2t["date"] != "Date", :]
```

Data -

```
          date stock closing_price
6   2020-12-11  TWTR         51.44
7   2020-12-11  SPOT        341.22
8   2020-12-11  PTON         117.1
9   2020-12-11  SHOP       1057.87
10  2020-12-11  MSFT        213.26
11  2020-12-11  TSLA        609.99
```

pandas.melt() on df1

```
df1m = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=["username"], value_vars=["Stock 1", "Stock 2"])
```

Data -

```
  username variable value
0   JB3004  Stock 1  TSLA
1   JM3009  Stock 1  SHOP
2   DB0208  Stock 1  TWTR
3   AB3011  Stock 1  TWTR
4   CB3004  Stock 1  MSFT
5   JB3004  Stock 2  MSFT
6   JM3009  Stock 2  SPOT
7   DB0208  Stock 2  MSFT
8   AB3011  Stock 2  PTON
9   CB3004  Stock 2  TSLA
```

Merge the dataframes.

```
df = pd.merge(df1m, df2t, left_on="value", right_on="stock", sort=False)
```

Data -

```
  username variable value        date stock closing_price
0   JB3004  Stock 1  TSLA  2020-12-11  TSLA        609.99
1   CB3004  Stock 2  TSLA  2020-12-11  TSLA        609.99
2   JM3009  Stock 1  SHOP  2020-12-11  SHOP       1057.87
3   DB0208  Stock 1  TWTR  2020-12-11  TWTR         51.44
4   AB3011  Stock 1  TWTR  2020-12-11  TWTR         51.44
5   CB3004  Stock 1  MSFT  2020-12-11  MSFT        213.26
6   JB3004  Stock 2  MSFT  2020-12-11  MSFT        213.26
7   DB0208  Stock 2  MSFT  2020-12-11  MSFT        213.26
8   JM3009  Stock 2  SPOT  2020-12-11  SPOT        341.22
9   AB3011  Stock 2  PTON  2020-12-11  PTON         117.1
```

Do some cleanup and then pivot for usable results

```
df = df.drop("value", axis=1).rename(columns={"variable": "holding_id"})
df = df.pivot(index="username", columns="holding_id", values=["stock", "closing_price"]).rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
```

Data -

```
             stock         closing_price        
holding_id Stock 1 Stock 2       Stock 1 Stock 2
username                                        
AB3011        TWTR    PTON         51.44   117.1
CB3004        MSFT    TSLA        213.26  609.99
DB0208        TWTR    MSFT         51.44  213.26
JB3004        TSLA    MSFT        609.99  213.26
JM3009        SHOP    SPOT       1057.87  341.22
```

Selecting data is pretty simple with multiindexing

```
df.loc[:,"stock"]["Stock 1"]
```

Data -

```
username
AB3011    TWTR
CB3004    MSFT
DB0208    TWTR
JB3004    TSLA
JM3009    SHOP
Name: Stock 1, dtype: object
```

Or, include username for targeted selections:

```
df.loc["AB3011","stock"]["Stock 1"]
```

Data -

```
'TWTR'
```